# Can I get a MOJO model using h2o-bindings api?

Tags: java, h2o

I am doing some DRF train using h2o-bindings and the code is copy from examples in h2o.

```
    GBMParametersV3 gbmParams = new GBMParametersV3();
    gbmParams.trainingFrame = H2oApi.stringToFrameKey("train");
    gbmParams.validationFrame = H2oApi.stringToFrameKey("test");

    ColSpecifierV3 responseColumn = new ColSpecifierV3();
    responseColumn.columnName = ATT_LABLE_IRIS;
    gbmParams.responseColumn = responseColumn;

    GBMV3 gbmBody = h2o.train_gbm(gbmParams);

    JobV3 job = h2o.waitForJobCompletion(gbmBody.job.key);

    ModelKeyV3 modelKey = (ModelKeyV3)job.dest;
    ModelsV3 models = h2o.model(modelKey);
    LogService.getRoot().log(Level.INFO,"models: " + models);

    GBMModelV3 model = (GBMModelV3)models.models[0];
```

But the GBMModelV3 doesn't have POJO and MOJO in source code.
As we can see it shows this.havePojo = false;

```
public class GBMModelV3 extends SharedTreeModelV3<GBMParametersV3, GBMModelOutputV3> {
public GBMModelV3() {
    this.checksum = 0L;
    this.algo = "";
    this.algoFullName = "";
    this.responseColumnName = "";
    this.timestamp = 0L;
    this.havePojo = false;
    this.haveMojo = false;
}

public String toString() {
    return (new Gson()).toJson(this);
}
```

}

So how can I get a MOJO model using h2o-bindings api? Or how can I get the tree information in the GBModelV3? Because the GBMModelV3 I got has so many parameters other than the final tree data.

The reason I want to get the MOJO model is that someone told me I can use h2o-genmodel to compute the "mojo_model.zip" and get the tree. But h2o-bindings, how to do it?